# Is there any way RIA Services Query Method can take Entity as Parameter?

Tags: silverlight, nhibernate, wcf-ria-services

I have zero way to pass a query to RIA Services.

You see; I have the unfortunate task of running NHibernate over Oracle, behind RIA Services and are not using NHibernate.Linq.

So, is there any way, any way at all to pass a object, my request object, back to a query?

Comment: I think the only work-around with this configuration is to use RIA to project entities down to client and stand-up (or in my case use existing) WCF service for queries....talk about SOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't pass the Entity. The problem is that #riaservices is key based so it expects that you will pass a key in query